# Refering to 2 css classes from within a textarea

Tags: html, css

Is it possible/permissible to refer to 2 css classes from within a text area like below:

with section 1 and section2 being classes from a css file. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more clear? Maybe add some example code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, both in the style sheet and in your HTML, I've used `div` for demonstration purposes, but the same applies to `textarea`

```css
.section1 {font-weight:bold;}
.section2 {font-style:italic;}
.section1.section2 {color:#f00;} /*Will only apply if both classes present*/
```

```html
<div class="section1">I'm bold</div>
<div class="section2">I'm italic</div>
<div class="section1 section2">I'm bold, italic and red!</div>
```

In HTML seperate multiple classes in the attribute with a space. To join multiple classes in your CSS have no speration between them

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean from within a text area? Do you mean something like the following...

`<textarea class="section1 section2"></textarea>`

Or do you mean CSS within the textarea itself? If so that's not possible because all you're typing into it is plain text. But you could target that text, for example...

`textarea.section1 { }`, `textarea.section2 { }` or `textarea.section1, textarea.section2 { }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it is possible to refer any number of classes within any html tag.

Ex:`<textarea class="section1 section2 section3"></textarea>`

and please provide space to separate the different classes html does not recognise if you use semicolon to separate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write both the classes without comma like

```
<textarea class="section1 section2"></textarea>
```

Now provide CSS code in your CSS file seperately.